# Reactjs function not returning JSX

Tags: reactjs, function, return, return-value

I am trying to write a function to return JSX, but it does not work, somehow. Are there any conflicts why my function is not returning any value. I've tried strings, lists, but it seems that nothing is returning.

**My function:**

```
const modifyScores = () => {
        teams.map(team => {
            if (team.team_name === activeTeam) {
                let scoresList = []

                Object.entries(team).map(([key, value]) => {
                    if (key.startsWith('r')) {
                        const obj = {"round": parseInt(key.substring(1)), "score": value}
                        scoresList.push(obj)
                    }
                })

                scoresList.sort((a, b) => a.round - b.round)
                
                console.log(scoresList)
                //return <Button>test</Button>
                return scoresList.map(s => <Button>r: {s.round}</Button>)
            }
        })
}
```

**My JSX:**

```
{modifyScores()}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do `return` inside `modifyScores()`.

```
const modifyScores = () => {
    return teams.map(team => {
            if (team.team_name === activeTeam) {
                let scoresList = []

                Object.entries(team).map(([key, value]) => {
                    if (key.startsWith('r')) {
                        const obj = {"round": parseInt(key.substring(1)), "score": value}
                        scoresList.push(obj)
                    }
                })

                scoresList.sort((a, b) => a.round - b.round)
                
                console.log(scoresList)
                //return <Button>test</Button>
                return scoresList.map(s => <Button>r: {s.round}</Button>)
            }
        })
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, it is actually working. Sorry for this rookie mistake. I am glad you helped me out since I was stuck for about 2 days now!

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

1. explicitly return the result of `teams.map()` inside of `modifyScores()` by prepending a return statement `return teams.map()`
2. remove the curly braces around `... => {teams.map()}`, which will return the result
   implicitly.

`modifyScores() => teams.map();`

For details take a look at the syntax of
arrow functions at the [MDN referrence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: Thank you for this additional information